# Steam market currency and XML format

Tags: http-headers, steam, steam-web-api

Im trying to get an item page on market in certain currency, tried to add

```
Accept-Language: ru-RU\r\n
```

and

```
Accept-Language: ru-RU, ru\r\n
```

and

```
Accept-Language: ru, ru-RU;q=0.8\r\n
```

to header but steam ignores it and always gives a page with mixed rubles, euros and dollars.

Also, how can i get a page in xml format? ?format=xml and ?xml=1 dont work, tried with `application/xml` and `*/*`

Comment: What is the URL you are attempting to get this information from?

Comment: http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/appid/itemname

Comment: What makes you believe the server is capable of providing the data in the format you want, and it's just a matter of finding the right incantation? It's not like every server in the world speaks XML when asked nicely enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Sellers will always list items for sale in the native currency of
>   their Steam Wallet, and buyers will always see Community Market prices
>   expressed in the native currency of their Steam Wallet. For items
>   listed for sale in a different currency than the buyer's Steam Wallet
>   currency, we apply an exchange rate which we update daily.
>   - Community Market [FAQ](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=6088-UDXM-7214#currency)

Meaning, if you are looking at the market from a browser you are logged in on and you have funds in your wallet that are not in Rubles, you won't see Rubles.

You can, however, get around this. If you log out of the market and visit your URL, there are two parameters you can pass for force language and region changes.

For example, using the ever popular Supply Crate Key: `http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/440/Mann%20Co.%20Supply%20Crate%20Key?l=russian&cc=ru`

Notice the `l` and `cc` parameters. The `l` is setting the language to Russian and the `cc` is setting the region to Russia.

Now, this doesn't appear to work on the entire page. The graph showing historical trends still appears to be in USD, even though the surrounding text is in Russian.

[image: USD Graph]

But, the individual listings of items did, in fact, change currencies.
[image: Listings]

Comment: I know about the parameters, tried to use ut many times but it doesnt work: http://hkar.ru/r2a8 http://hkar.ru/r2a9 Anyway, thanks for the answer

Comment: I just tried this and while the language change worked, the currency change did not seem to be applied.

Comment: Same here. Language changes but listings currencies don't. Any idea how to enforce one currency (whatever it is) for all items without being logged in?

Answer (score 6):

Recently Valve added market prices on inventory page when inspecting an item. The price is loaded through AJAX, and through inspecting network requests I found this:

http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?country=US&currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=AWP%20|%20Electric%20Hive%20(Factory%20New)

You can force currency with this (currency 3 is EUR), returns lowest price on market and median price, JSON format.

Comment: Hi, it shows Euro when I put currency as 3, did any update/change happened?

Comment: @Sid ups, I messed up, currency 1 is USD, currency 3 is EUR. :)

Comment: I figured as much by trial and error. Thank you for this, I can easily get the median. Did you saw this from a document site anywhere?

Answer (score 6):

If someone still needs this:
http://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?start=0&count=10&l=english&currency=5&q=&category_730_ItemSet%5B%5D=any&category_730_TournamentTeam%5B%5D=any&category_730_Weapon%5B%5D=tag_weapon_ak47&category_730_Exterior%5B%5D=tag_WearCategory0&category_730_Quality%5B%5D=tag_strange&appid=730

`l` param (Language): english, russian, french, etc.

`count` is how much results to display

`start` is starting result (`start=10&count=10` is 2nd page with 10 results)

`currency`: 5 = ruble, 3 = USD. There are many others.

http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/StatTrak%E2%84%A2%20AK-47%20%7C%20Blue%20Laminate%20%28Factory%20New%29/render?start=0&count=5&currency=5&language=english

Comment: Thank, Alex Hide, this is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Do you know if this works with URLs "by name" ? Ex: http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/440/Strange%20Concheror
It seems not, to me, but maybe there are tricks.

Comment: @Gnurfos http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/440/Strange%20Concheror/render/?query=&start=10&count=10&country=UK&language=english&currency=3 this maybe

Comment: Hum it seems to return something, but I cannot make sense of the results, nor make currency vary apparently. Are currencies (or other parameters) documented somewhere ? (there seems to be a currency_id in output, different from the parameter too). Where do you find these URLs too ? Thanks

Comment: @Gnurfos, Open steam market, open Developer console in browser or any http sniffer and change market page (ex. from 1 -> 2). You will see http get request.

Comment: I did that, but it doesn't seem to behave the same way by "scripting" as when I'm logged in. I get listings in mixed currencies whatever the currency parameter (just as in the original question or comments to the accepted answer). It must be reading only cookies, not parameters (or worse: session data, because there's not that many cookies).

Comment: @Gnurfos I think what you need is converted_price + converted_fee params. It works well for me even if I clean my cookies.

Comment: The first link does not work at all. When I go to the link with my logged in account, I just get my default currecy, and when I go to hte link without being logged in I always get USD, even if I change the currency integer.

Comment: @SaifBechan Both works fine for me (latest Chrome, incognito tab).

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of getting different currency outputs using the first link. Maybe euro, usd, and rubbles. In incognito tab I always get USD currency as JSON output, and im from Europe.