# Conserve Steam cookies over PHP script

Tags: php, cookies, curl, steam

For a personnal project, I have to get the prices of an item on the community market. To be simple, I can take this item : http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/StatTrak%E2%84%A2%20P250%20%7C%20Steel%20Disruption%20%28Factory%20New%29. Simply, I have a PHP script getting the ten prices of the page and displaying them. The only problem is, unless you're connected, Steam shows prices in the currency the seller uses (so it can be euro as much as dollar). My problem is I have to convert it and it's pretty... difficult. So my idea is to use my Chrome cookies and use cURL to get the page, and then I have all my prices in euro. Can anyone say me how to do it ?
Thank you in advance
Thomas

Comment: How does a cookie help when the prices are mixed?

Comment: Simply when you are logged in, prices are displayed in your currency.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22616644/steam-market-currency-and-xml-format/22623700#22623700

Comment: Yeah thanks it's perfect. I just need to know how to have the prices in euro now ^^