# Establish language called JSON

Tags: php, json, steam

This is my problem. I explain:

I use Firefox. If I set the browser language to English, the following page displays text in Spanish, but the currency in dollars.
[Link](http://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?l=spanish&start=0&count=20&currency=3&category_730_Weapon%5B%5D=tag_weapon_awp&appid=730&query=Man-o%27-war)

The same URL, If I set the browser language to Spanish, the texts are displayed in Spanish and currency in Euros.

I created a script with PHP using JSON: How I can set the language for calls?
The following code, ALWAYS returns the English language:

```
<?php
$url = "http://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?l=spanish&start=0&count=20&currency=3&category_730_Weapon%5B%5D=tag_weapon_awp&appid=730&query=Man-o%27-war";
$json_object= file_get_contents($url);
$json_decoded = json_decode($json_object);


//precios
preg_match_all('/<span style="color:white">(.*)<\/span>/',$json_decoded->results_html, $sor);

foreach($sor[1] as $k => $v)
{
    echo $v."<br/>";
}

?>
```

I want the currency Euros. I tried adding the following modifications, but the currency result is always English:

```
<html lang="es">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="es"/>

</head>
<body>
<?php

$locale = Locale::acceptFromHttp($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
echo $locale."<br/>";

$options = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: es\r\n" . 
              "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n")
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);

$url = "http://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?l=spanish&start=0&count=20&currency=3&category_730_Weapon%5B%5D=tag_weapon_awp&appid=730&query=Man-o%27-war";
$json_object= file_get_contents($url,false,$context);
$json_decoded = json_decode($json_object);


//precios
preg_match_all('/<span style="color:white">(.*)<\/span>/',$json_decoded->results_html, $sor);

foreach($sor[1] as $k => $v)
{
    echo $v."<br/>";
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your help. Greetings.

Comment: I modified the apache configuration file. This line: LanguagePriority en cs de fr es it ja ko nl pl pt-br ro sv tr Changed by LanguagePriority es en cs de fr it ja ko nl pl pt-br ro sv tr .but no positive result. The display language remains English

Comment: have you seen my answer? Check the link I posted - it is the modified link with the correct spanish text

Comment: Thank you very much Darragh. Your reply helped me to leave the texts in Spanish. Now the problem is that the currency remains Dollars. I edited the issue with the upgrade.

Comment: Hi. Updated my answer. Not sure if it'll be helpful but hopefully it's a lead.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo. Specifically, in your url. You are saying `?l=espanish`. It should be `?l=spanish`:

> http://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?l=spanish&start=0&count=20&currency=3&category_730_Weapon%5B%5D=tag_weapon_awp&appid=730&query=Man-o%27-war

**Edit**

I don't have any more answers unfortunately, but I came across the following SO answer which might be helpful. It would seem that the currency shown is contextual - I guess you need to be logged in via your script?

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/22623700/312962

Anyway, I hope this helps!

Comment: This answer is useful +1, but my low reputation does not allow me to vote

Answer (score 0):

for the currency you have **&currency=**
**3**: USD
**2**: € (i believe, try it)